# На эмуляторе Android Studio пропадает интернет при установке сертификата proxyman

Tags: android-studio, proxy, эмулятор

Создала проект в android studio, создала эмулятор, запускаю эмулятор из терминала. В прохсимен выпустила сертификат, доверила его, добавила файлы xml в проект, в общем следовала инстуркции [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сертификат установился на эмулятор, в настройках прописала настройки прокси: локальный адрес и порт (как у проксимена). Но после этого пропадает интернет в эмуляторе и в проксимене вообще не появляется эмулятор, хотя пару дней назад все работало и я пользовалась несколько месяцев успешно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовала и в настройках самого эмулятора добавлять настройки прокси, отключать их, передавать сертификат через непосредственную установку на эмулятор файлом, пересмотрела сотни видео, ничего не помогает, в один день перестало работать и все...
С charles такая же история. В чем может быть проблема?